# Internet Explorer, Окно повтора загрузки страницы, откуда родом?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, javascript

Из-за чего может вылезать это окошко в IE? Не знаю куда копать. Но после того как я нажимаю повтор некоторые стили и иконки пропадают.

[image: Windows Internet Explorer]

Доп. Кстати по мимо этого окошка вылазит еще одно:

[image: Совместимость чего-то]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из-за наличия на странице данных, переданных методом POST.

Comment: да нету таких, мне на другом форуме тоже это говорят, но не отправлял я никаких POST.

Comment: я обновился.

Comment: @Maris, смотрите в сторону `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" ... />`. А для того, чтобы оценить про повторную отправку формы - данных маловато.